# How to understand "Astrology was a symbolic constant all over the world" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> My French stinks, Langdon thought, but my zodiac iconography  is pretty good. Taurus was always the bull. ***Astrology was a symbolic constant all over the world***.
>
> <sub>The Da Vinci Code</sub>

[Astrology](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Astrology) is well defined in dictionaries:

> The study of the positions and motions of celestial bodies in the belief that they have an influence on the course of natural earthly occurrences and human affairs.

I don't understand why "*Astrology was a symbolic constant all over the world*". How should we understand it in this context?

Comment: It might be added that this sentence is a little strange: he means "Symbols in astrology are constant all over the world."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that the symbolism of astrology, so for instance constellation of Taurus as a bull. Was always identified as a bull, irregardless of what culture saw it.

So he's saying that aztecs, vikings, africans etc. all saw the constellations, and used the same symbols for them. So even if he doesn't speak their language, he can "read" the symbols, because they have the same meaning in all languages.